# Uninstall jenkins.war from Mac OS

Tags: java, spring, jenkins

Someone could help me?

I'm using Jenkins with Mac OS. First one I downloaded the file jenkins.war, double click, and then Jenkins is running. Ok, until now no problem! But, when I started one new java spring project using Eclipse some days after, I started my Spring application and then I realize Jenkins is running I don't know how and why in port 8080.

My user is marco, so I realize one hide folder /Users/marco/.jenkins/

I removed this folder and started one more time my spring project but in localhost:8080 appears the login and password page from Jenkins again.

I also tried change the port of my spring project like 7000 or 8089, anyway, always I started my Spring application always appears the Login page from Jenkins I don't know why.

I also tried delete the jenkins.war from my Download folder in my Mac OS but no changes.

I also tried start the jenkins.war with one parameter to specific one different port, in this case the Jenkins open in this different port and also in port 8080! Oh my God! What's it?

I suspect when I clicked in the jenkins.war probably was made one deploy in a tomcat embedded version.

Thank you so much!

Marco A Pereira.

Comment: Where did you download it? Look there for clues, or at least post the download page so others can help you figure out what you did.

Comment: can you check which port is used by which process and then kill that process: `sudo lsof -i tcp:8080`, add any port in place of 8080

Comment: Hi! I downloaded from this site: https://jenkins.io/download/  >>> Long-term Support (LTS)  >>> Generic Java package (.war).